# rm -rf /home/ Recovery

Tags: linux, rm, data-recovery

OS :-Suse Linux Enterprise 12.0
File System :- ext3

I hit `rm -rf /home/`, immediately I did <kbd>Contol</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> so the command got canceled but until that time I lost ~9GB of data from this `/home` dir.

I don't have System GUI access. Please suggest a suitable recovery command or packages so that i can recover my lost `/home` files.

I just want to recover only one lost dir from this `/home` dir that is, `/home/cubot/etl/script`. This `/home/cubot/etl/script` was having some important scripts and it is not visible now completely.

Answer (score 0):

As those are important files for you, you probably have a backup somewhere. So recover the files from there.

If you do not have a backup (why not?!), it gets complicated or even impossible. It's really important not doing anything with this computer. As every write access to the hard drive gives the chance that you overwrite those "deleted" files.

Because you use ext3, go to [this page](http://batleth.sapienti-sat.org/projects/FAQs/ext3-faq.html), scroll down to "*Q: How can I recover (undelete) deleted files from my ext3 partition?*" and read. I hope for you that this information is wrong.

What you can try is: boot from a live cd which has data recovery tools on it (you'll find plenty of such tools on the net). eg. one of such a tool is Testdisk, [Scalpel](http://www.tecmint.com/install-scalpel-a-filesystem-recovery-tool-to-recover-deleted-filesfolders-in-linux/) or extundelete.

Google to find more tools and guides. I personally have no experience with those tools, as I learned to do backups after two complete datalosts in my life.

(*Unfortunately, my reputation is to low to add more than two links, otherwise I would have linked the tools. But I'm sure you know how to google it.*)